# Python unittest - Display all AssertionError within same test

Tags: python, python-unittest

How to I get the code below to print all AssertionErrors within a given test?  To be clear I'm not looking to create additional tests. Thank you!

```
import unittest

def lbs_to_stones(lbs):
    return lbs/14

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_lbs_to_stones(self):
        self.assertEqual(lbs_to_stones(140),10)
        self.assertEqual(lbs_to_stones(150),11)
        self.assertEqual(lbs_to_stones(14),61)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
AssertionError: 10.714285714285714 != 11

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by printing them all? There is only one error, the test does not continue when an assertion fails

Comment: @Mark yes but the test exits as soon as an assertion fails. The third assertion is never run

Comment: @Joe, this is exactly what I was looking for thanks!